# Is there a way to speed up time just a little bit?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

Let's say a large UFO is detected but I only have poorly equipped interceptors in the area. I have a Firestorm with plasma cannons in transfer, but it's going to take another few hours to get to that continent.

Clicking "Scan for Activity" guarantees that I'm going to miss the UFO, but I'm also not a fan of either losing an interceptor just to show I did something with the UFO or sitting there staring at the clock waiting for hours to go by.

Can I/how do I change how fast time goes by without clicking "Scan for Activity"?

Comment: FWIW I've had luck taking down the large UFO just by using a standard interceptor and the first gun upgrade by using the one time use items.

Comment: FWIW you can send out an interceptor and then hit Abort as soon as it engages. It shouldn't take more than a tiny amount of damage, and does mark the UFO as one you've tried to deal with (so the country doesn't panic). Doesn't directly help with the question as asked though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way to do this is to just quickly tap <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice to advance time just a little bit. I wish there was a way to set which events stopped the scan, but they don't seem to have implemented that function.